# Git status: Coloring deleted files

Tags: colors, git

I'm running git 2.17.0 on Cygwin.

Doing a `git config --get-regexp color` shows me

```
....
color.status.added bold yellow
color.status.changed red
color.status.untracked white
color.status.branch bold blue
color.status.deleted yellow
color.status.header bold white
....
color.branch.local yellow
....
```

But when I do a `git status`, the "modified" and the "deleted" files are displayed in the same colour (red). Note also that in my terminal configuration, "yellow" *is* defined as visibly different colour from "red", as I can see when I do a `git branch`, which shows the local branches in the correct colour.

My best guess is that git considers a file from the repo, which I have deleted, for some reason as a 'modified' file, but then I wonder, what the color.status.deleted setting is supposed to mean.

Anybody having an explanation for this? Can other people reproduce this?

Answer (score 2):

There are two different type of *deleted* file in git status.

Suppose that I have a file, regularly commited, called "deleteme" in my git repo. I can do two things:

1. I can do `rm deleteme`. At this point, the file is simply modified, from a git point of view, and so it is shown in **red**.

   ```
   ~/Wip/sample $ rm deleteme
   ~/Wip/sample $ git status
   Sul branch master
   Changes not staged for commit:
     (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
     (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

   deleted:    deleteme
   ```
2. I can do `git rm deleteme` (or `rm deleteme; git add deleteme`). At this point the file is deleted and its deletion is in the index, ready to be committed. From the git pov this file is a "deleted" one and so it is shown in **yellow**.

   ```
   ~/Wip/sample $ git rm deleteme
   ~/Wip/sample $ git status
   Sul branch master
   Changes to be committed:
     (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

       deleted:    deleteme
   ```

P.S. Obviously, in my explanation, the colours are as for your configuration.

Comment: Finally I understood that there *is* a difference between `rm` and `git rm`! I always wondered why git has its own `rm` and `mv` commands.....